# Command to automatically input password for pscp

Tags: batch-file, pscp

I want to copy some file to a remote Linux system from my Windows PC using `pscp` (from putty). I wrote a small script that call the pscp commands in this way:

```
"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\pscp.exe" -scp C:\Users\hp\Desktop\scripts\* root@192.168.1.177:/root/scripts
"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\pscp.exe" -scp C:\Users\hp\Desktop\scripts2\* root@192.168.1.177:/root/scripts2 

pause
```

But when I launch this bat script, I'm asked to input the password, so I input the password manually.

Is there a way to input the password automatically through the batch file?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From putty [documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter5.html)

> **5.2.2.6 -pw passw** login with specified password
>
> If a password is required to connect to the host, PSCP will
>   interactively prompt you for it. However, this may not always be
>   appropriate. If you are running PSCP as part of some automated job, it
>   will not be possible to enter a password by hand. The -pw option to
>   PSCP lets you specify the password to use on the command line.

Answer (score 56):

```
pscp -pw yourPasswordHere C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\test.sh testUser@123.123.123.123:/home/testUser
```

I've noticed that no one posted sample of that command with -pw option.

Comment: This was the most straightforward, and best best answer.

Comment: note to anyone in future the order of -pw needs to be first and then file name that you are trying to upload

Comment: The syntax usage from the documentation is pretty clear that the `[options]` come first.

Comment: To automate this: `echo y | pscp -pw ...` (edit: do not use -batch param)

Answer (score 6):

You can work this stuff out for yourself. Use the `/?` option to see the help. The pertinent parts are included below.

```
>pscp /?
PuTTY Secure Copy client
Release 0.60
Usage: pscp [options] [user@]host:source target
       pscp [options] source [source...] [user@]host:target
       pscp [options] -ls [user@]host:filespec
Options:
......
  -l user   connect with specified username
  -pw passw login with specified password
......
```

Use the `-l` and `-pw` options to specify a user and password.

So whilst that answers the specific question that you asked, the real opportunity for you is to learn how to obtain documentation from command line utilities.

Comment: This answer sounds somewhat condescending, but it is absolutely true!  Learn about your utility's included documentation before you ask, you can save a lot of time.  I spent a day trying to figure out some linux options to a module I was installing and searched all over the internet to no avail, but the answer was right there if I had only done a `man <module>`.  One forehead slap later, and it's a lesson I'll never forget.

Answer (score 0):

Use putty to set up a remote login without a password.  This will involve the puttygen command.  You will need a private key and the target will need a public key.  Once you verified that you have a good private key file and login without typing a password, you can reference it with the "-i" private key option on pscp.  You might be able to set up the key without the putty connect if it isn't allowed, but this is the easiest way. Just say no to passwords in the clear:

```
C:\Users\riglerjo>pscp -i .ssh\rigler_rsa.ppk test.txt rigler@rigler.org:.
test.txt                  | 0 kB |   0.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

Comment: You need a privatekey and the target needs *the* (specific) publickey *derived from* your privatekey, in `.ssh/authorized_keys`. But if your privatekey file has a passphrase, which usually it should, you are still prompted. To avoid *that*, use `pageant` which is the putty equivalent of `ssh-agent`; it keeps your privatekey in memory and uses it without re-prompting but only until you logoff or shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

If your coping a local file to remote directory use:

```
pscp -pw yourPasswordHere C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\test.sh testUser@10.10.10.10:/home/testUser
```

If your coping a remote file to local directory use:

```
pscp -pr yourPasswordHere testUser@10.10.10.10:/home/testUser/test.sh C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ pscp -pw "speci4l^()Ch4rs" -r -sftp C:/Users/username/code/scp/* username@example.com:/var/www/example.com/public_html/scp
```

Windows 11, using MINGW64 (Git bash), use double quotes for the password.

- -pw Password
- -r Recursive
- -sftp Force encrypted transfer

Order can be important.

Answer (score -1):

```
sshpass -p'password' pscp -A -H "ip" -t 20 -l root /var/www/html/temp_santosh.txt /tmp/
```

You can use `sshpass` with `-p` option just before `pscp`